# Problem BEGINS() Workflow

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

The criteria is to trigger the workflow on the opportunity if

```
OR( 
NOT(BEGINS( Account.BillingPostalCode , "1")), 
NOT(BEGINS(Account.BillingPostalCode , "2")), 
ISBLANK( Account.BillingPostalCode ) 
)
```

To test it, I created opportunity with Account.BillingPostalCode = 1111. 
Logically, the WF must return false. but it returned true and WF executed

Pleas explain what is wrong here.

Comment: Whats the WF trigger condition? Created, Created and Edited, or Subsequent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saumya.
Logically your test must return true.

```
OR( 
NOT(BEGINS( "1111" , "1")), 
NOT(BEGINS("1111" , "2")), 
ISBLANK( "1111" ) 
)
```

Returns `OR(false, true, false) = true`.

You might need to fix the workflow formula